# Counting Question on choosing songs from a 7-song playlist (Discrete math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A playlist consist of songs from two Broadway musicals: Les Miserables and Mamma Mia. I have 40 Les Mis tracks saved on Spotify, and 19 from Mamma Mia. Order matters, repetition allowed and I prefer to keep answer in form n^k or a combination.

Questions and what I have tried so far:

- Suppose my playlist contains 7 songs. How many playlists could I create? 59^7
- Suppose my 7-song playlist contains songs from one show or the other but not both. Now how many playlists are possible? 40^7 + 19^7
- What if my playlist could contain 7 to 10 songs, but they’re all from Les Mis. Now how many playlists are possible? 40^7 + 40^8 + 40^9 + 40^10
- What if Kayla sticks to 7 songs in her playlist, but wants to play at least one from each show. Repeated songs are still OK. Now how many playlists are possible? 59^7 - 40^7 - 19^7 or (40 1) * (19 1) * 59^5

Would these be correct?

Comment: Playlists on Spotify are ordered sequences of distinct tracks. $59^7$ counts sequences with repetition.

Comment: Ignoring what the actual app allows and sticking with the parameters you gave, all of your answers are correct.